# Optimal way of matlab to python communication

Tags: python, matlab, communication

So I am working on a Matlab application that has to do some communication with a Python script. The script that is called is a simple client software. As a side note, if it would be possible to have a Matlab client and a Python server communicating this would solve this issue completely but I haven't found a way to work that out.

Anyhow, after searching the web I have found two ways to call Python scripts, either by the `system()` command or editing the *perl.m* file to call Python scripts instead. Both ways are too slow though (`tic` tocing them to > 20ms and must run faster than 6ms) as this call will be in a loop that is very time sensitive.

As a solution I figured I could instead save a file at a certain location and have my Python script continuously check for this file and when finding it executing the command I want it to. Now after timing each of these steps and summing them up I found it to be incredibly much faster (almost 100x so for sure fast enough) and I cant really believe that, or rather I cant understand why calling python scripts is so slow (not that I have more than a superficial knowledge of the subject). I also found this solution to be really messy and ugly so just wanted to check that, first, is it a good idea and second, is there a better one?

Finally, I realize that the Python `time.time()` and Matlab `tic`, `toc` might not be precise enough to measure time correctly on that scale so also a reason why I ask.

Comment: Are you saying that [status,cmdout] = system('python pyscript.py') takes 20ms, but save('flagfile.txt') and then reading the output from the deamon python process takes .2ms?
How do you even get the output of the python process in the second case ('cmdout')? 
A guess as to why the latter is faster is that the python process is already started, while in the first case you need to start a process, load the python interpretter, etc. 
I would look into using named pipes (on *nix), although matlab doesn't seem to make that too easy.

Comment: Scratch the negative comment about matlab+named pipes above, you can just use fopen, fscanf etc on the named pipe, so now all you need to do is open the corresponding pipes on the python end as well and come up with an appropriate communication protocol for the output

Comment: Thanks, I went with named pipe, nice enough solution and for sure quick enough.

Answer (score 1):

Spinning up new instances of the Python interpreter takes a while. If you spin up the interpreter once, and reuse it, this cost is paid only once, rather than for every run.

This is normal (expected) behaviour, since startup includes large numbers of allocations and imports. For example, on my machine, the startup time is:

```
$ time python -c 'import sys'

real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.022s
sys     0m0.011s
```